# Parse LocalDateTime format

Tags: java-8

Is there a way to parse `2018-09-17T17:13:13.741` to `2018-09-17 17:13:13`. I was trying with :

```
LocalDateTime startDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime.parse(startDateTime, FORMATTER);
```

With combinations I either get a parse exception or `2018-09-17T17:13:13`.

Note: I do not need the `T` and milliseconds

Comment: `startDateTime.format(FORMATTER);`

Comment: Word usage: “Parsing” is converting from a string to a `LocalDateTime`. The opposite conversion is called “formatting”. It seems to me you want to use the `format` method rather than the `parse` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) like this:

```
LocalDateTime startDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
startDateTime.format(FORMATTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of DateTimeFormatter you can directly use the LocalDateTime to get a year, month, day, hours, minutes and seconds.

The below code may work for your scenario.

```
LocalDateTime startDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        int year = startDateTime.getYear();
        int month = startDateTime.getMonthValue();
        int day = startDateTime.getDayOfMonth();

        int hours = startDateTime.getHour();
        int minute = startDateTime.getMinute();
        int seconds = startDateTime.getSecond();
        int nanoSeconds = startDateTime.getNano();

        String date = year +"-"+month+"-"+day+" "+hours+":"+minute+":"+seconds;
        System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: This is the cumbersome way, not recommended. Also it will give the month as `9` where `09` was asked for.